# Hacked web site only in google search results?

Tags: googlebot

when i search for my site: mladinski center trbovlje, the first result is some iphone chinese version.. but when i visit it, it goes ok to my site: mct.si

I checked with google webmaster i get this results: redirected to: http://eumoil.com/chaneliphone6_1.html

My .htaccess is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent serving TYPO3 404 pages for missing files
RewriteRule ^(typo3(conf|temp)?|fileadmin|uploads|t3lib|clear.gif|index.php|favicon.ico) - [L]

# Do not rewrite static resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Rewrite the rest to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I dont find the redirection anywhere on my site, also site is working normally, so where is this redirection hiding?

Answer (score 0):

your site might be hacked.
as you still use outdated version TYPO3 4.7 which got no security fixes someone might be broke in to your server and install some special scripts.

there might be a script which is only visible for googlebots to show them special content (e.g. links to spam-sites, ...) and every other access gets the 'normal' content. now you should inspect the default files which gets executed on an access: *index.php*, which normaly is symlinked to `/typo3_src/index.php`. is there some special unusual code?

you also might compare the complete sources of your TYPO3 to the original version, which you might get from get.typo3.org if no security fixes have occured meanwhile.
other installed software may need also a compare to find the intrusion.
last: look for any installed software which might get executed remotely which might reinstall bad code.

**in general:** keep your software updated to the newest secure state.